# Mooc course: Is there a way to get this piece of code to work without the break; at the end?

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-8

I got this error from running the code without the break; at the end and by searching for it that was a solution i came up with on my own but i was wondering is there a better way to handle it.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SummanNeliojuuri {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner lukija = new Scanner(System.in);

    while(true) {
        int luku = Integer.valueOf(lukija.nextLine());
        int luku2 = Integer.valueOf(lukija.nextLine());
        int summa = luku + luku2;
        int neliojuuri = (int) Math.sqrt(summa);
        System.out.println(neliojuuri);
        break; }
    }
}
```

Just that the code runs without the error. Not sure though that if the error comes up only because im running it through a mooc course "inspector" in netbeans.

Comment: Which error did you get? You state that you got this error, but never actually write what it says.

Comment: Why do you need to use `while`?

Comment: You always break the cycle. It's pointless to use `while` with unconditional `break`.

Comment: If you remove the break it is an infinite loop. The inspector may be doing you a favor and saying after a while that it is timing out or refusing to do too many loops. Like @AlekseyIsachenkov says, presumably you want to ask something like "Enter m for more or q to quit", read the response, and then decide whether to break.

Answer (score -1):

Aaaah okay that cleared it up. Took the while loop away from it. I assumed the inspection thing in netbeans needed the loop for it for some reason. Also i didnt think that the break was needed here. Thanks a lot all of you! :)

also the error i got was: java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found

edit: Really thankful for all the help! Was a bit afraid to post something since i knew it was a really "noobie" question. Got rid of the while loop and the break and it works great now!